# YouTube Upload Widget Can't Set Privacy

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube Upload Widget (https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget) but can't seem to set the privacy to 'unlisted'. The title and description however work fine. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
function onApiReady(event) {
    widget.setVideoTitle(job_title_var);
    widget.setVideoDescription(job_description_var);
    widget.setVideoPrivacy("unlisted");
  }
```

Thanks,
Andy.

Comment: We're looking into it; if you'd like to track it more formally, could you please file a bug via https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an unfortunate bug, which has since been fixed. `setVideoPrivacy()` should work as documented right now.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem as Andy.

widget.setPrivacy("unlisted") is not working, videos are being uploaded with Privacy Setting set to Public (the default).

I filed a bug https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4855 earlier today.

Thanks for looking into it,

Laura